# could not load library "/usr/pgsql-10/lib/postgis-2.5.so": /usr/pgsql-10/lib/postgis-2.5.so: undefined symbol: GEOSFrechetDistanceDensify

Tags: postgis, postgresql-10

I have installed postgresql 10 on centos 7.4 and installed postgis2.5 few months back. The installation was successful and Iam able to use postgis. All of a sudden Iam getting the following error.

```
test=# create extension postgis ;
ERROR:  could not load library "/usr/pgsql-10/lib/postgis-2.5.so": /usr/pgsql-10/lib/postgis-2.5.so: undefined symbol: GEOSFrechetDistanceDensify
```

And ldd on postgis-2.5.so is as follows

```
lib]# ldd postgis-2.5.so 
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffcc03ef000)
    libgeos_c.so.1 => /usr/geos36/lib64/libgeos_c.so.1 (0x00007f7a7d766000)
    libproj.so.12 => /usr/proj49/lib/libproj.so.12 (0x00007f7a7d4fd000)
    libjson-c.so.2 => /lib64/libjson-c.so.2 (0x00007f7a7d2f2000)
    libxml2.so.2 => /lib64/libxml2.so.2 (0x00007f7a7cf88000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f7a7cc86000)
    libSFCGAL.so.1 => /lib64/libSFCGAL.so.1 (0x00007f7a7c1b7000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f7a7bdea000)
    libgeos-3.6.3.so => /usr/geos36/lib64/libgeos-3.6.3.so (0x00007f7a7ba3c000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f7a7b735000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f7a7b51f000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f7a7b303000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f7a7b0ff000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007f7a7aee9000)
    liblzma.so.5 => /lib64/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007f7a7acc3000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f7a7dc56000)
    libCGAL.so.11 => /usr/lib64/libCGAL.so.11 (0x00007f7a7aa9b000)
    libCGAL_Core.so.11 => /usr/lib64/libCGAL_Core.so.11 (0x00007f7a7a862000)
    libmpfr.so.4 => /usr/lib64/libmpfr.so.4 (0x00007f7a7a607000)
    libgmp.so.10 => /usr/lib64/libgmp.so.10 (0x00007f7a7a38f000)
    libboost_date_time-mt.so.1.53.0 => /usr/lib64/libboost_date_time-mt.so.1.53.0 (0x00007f7a7a17e000)
    libboost_thread-mt.so.1.53.0 => /usr/lib64/libboost_thread-mt.so.1.53.0 (0x00007f7a79f67000)
    libboost_system-mt.so.1.53.0 => /usr/lib64/libboost_system-mt.so.1.53.0 (0x00007f7a79d63000)
    libboost_serialization-mt.so.1.53.0 => /usr/lib64/libboost_serialization-mt.so.1.53.0 (0x00007f7a79af7000)
    librt.so.1 => /usr/lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007f7a798ef000)
```

The function GEOSFrechetDistanceDensify seems to be added in version 3.7 of Geos as in link below & I have geos 3.6. Is this the reason for this error?.
https://trac.osgeo.org/geos/browser/git/NEWS?rev=3.7.0

Please help me to get the issue resolved.

Comment: " installed postgis2.5 few months back." how did you install it? Same for postgreSQL. What did change before the error started? Did you upgrade anything?

Comment: I referred to the following link. http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/362-An-almost-idiots-guide-to-install-PostgreSQL-9.5,-PostGIS-2.2-and-pgRouting-2.1.0-with-Yum.html              And post-gis has got auto updated.

Comment: Yum log -Nov 29 21:24:44 Installed: geos37-3.7.0-1.rhel7.x86_64
Nov 29 21:24:45 Updated: postgis25_10-2.5.1-1.rhel7.x86_64
Nov 29 21:24:45 Updated: postgis25_10-client-2.5.1-1.rhel7.x86_64

Comment: I reinstalled postgis2.4 from source and got the issue resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem on CentOS after an update. I had 3.6 AND 3.7 installed.

> $yum list installed | grep geos
>
> geos36.x86_64                           3.6.3-1.rhel7                  @pgdg10
> geos37.x86_64                           3.7.0-1.rhel7                  @pgdg10

I had to remove the 3.6:

> $yum remove geos36

And restart PostgreSQL

> $systemctl restart postgresql-10